# checking if Document object is in JSON format in java

Tags: java, json, document

I have a function that returns a Document object in java - how would one go about checking whether this Document object is in JSON format or not?

Comment: You mean the file contains content in JSON format or XML format?

Comment: You can use toString() on Document to get String and then using Gson library, convert it to Json, if there is an error in conversion it is not valid Json, otherwise it is valid

Comment: Why do you need to check? What is the alternative?

Comment: Try parsing it, if it works it is json.

Comment: check https://www.json.org/json-en.html they have many options for you

Comment: @hiren I mean Document object contains content in JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code: It will get the document object as String as then parse it to check whether it is a JSON object or a JSON array.

```
// IMPORTS USED
// import org.json.*;

Document doc = // YOUR DOCUMENT OBJECT;
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
try {
    new JSONObject(writer.toString());
    // IS JSON OBJECT
} catch(JSONException ex) {
  // NOT JSON OBJECT
    try {
        new JSONArray(writer.toString());
        // IS JSON ARRAY
    } catch(JSONException ex1) {
        // NOT JSON ARRAY
    }
}
```